# how to write django test meant to fail?

Tags: django, testing, tdd

I have a model called `Thing` with an attribute called `name`, and I want name to be a char field that's *only* 3 characters long.

How do I write a test for that?

```
class TestCase1(TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        thing = Thing(name='1234')
```

that test should fail. How do I properly write the test so that the test *passes* when that object fails?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you're expecting Thing(name='1234') to raise an exception, there are two ways to deal with this.

One is to use Django's assertRaises (actually from unittest/unittest2):

```
def mytest(self):
    self.assertRaises(FooException, Thing, name='1234')
```

This fails unless Thing(name='1234') raises a FooException error.  Another way is to catch the expected exception and raise one if it doesn't happen, like this:

```
def mytest(self):
    try:
        thing = Thing(name='1234')
        self.fail("your message here")
    except FooException:
        pass
```

Obviously, replace the FooException with the one you expect to get from creating the object with too long a string.  ValidationError?

A third option (as of Python 2.7) is to use assertRaises as a context manager, which makes for cleaner, more readable code:

```
def mytest(self):
    with self.assertRaises(FooException):
        thing = Thing(name='1234')
```

Sadly, this doesn't allow for custom test failure messages, so document your tests well.  See https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/unittest/case.py#l97 for more details.

Comment: I use assertRaises quite often.

Comment: I do as well, but the syntax takes some getting used to.

Comment: in python version 2.6.5, the function signature is different. Copied from python code: `def failUnlessRaises(self, excClass, callableObj, *args, **kwargs)` and then `callableObj(*args, **kwargs)`. So in this post's example, it would be `self.assertRaises(FooException, Thing, name='1234')`. I'm not sure why my function signature is different, but that's what works.

Comment: Actually, I think it's been that way for some time.  I just got the sig backwards.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: `assertRaises` can also be used in a with statement like this:
`with self.assertRaises(FooException):
    thing = Thing(name='1234')`

Comment: That is to say, assertRaises is also a context manager.  See the example use case here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8215739/402605

Comment: In case you run into a `TransactionManagementError`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326971

Answer (score 7):

I am currently using the `expectedFailure` decorator from [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.expectedFailure). That works as advertised: Fails when there is no error, passes when there is a failure.

I use `expectedFailure` to verify that my custom assert-routines actually work and not just rubberstamp everything OK.

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase

class EmojiTestCase(TestCase):

    @unittest.expectedFailure
    def testCustomAssert(self):
        self.assertHappyFace(':(') # must fail.
```

But prints a warning-message during testing. I use it with Django and Nose. Which [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431020/nosetest-and-unittest-expectedfailures) have seen, too.

> /usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py:525: RuntimeWarning: TestResult has no addExpectedFailure method, reporting as passes
>     RuntimeWarning)

I came here to find a better solution, but found none. So I at least wanted to tell others that come what I've been working with.

Answer (score 7):

In my previous project i had to do something like test driven development, so i have written some test case which must catch certain types of error. If it don't gets the error then i have messed up something. Here i share my code.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ModelTest(TestCase):

def test_create_user_with_email(self):

    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        email = "ah@gmail.com"
        password = 'testpass1'

        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = email,
            password = password,)

        self.assertEqual(user.email, email)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(password))
```

You can see i have tried to create a user with email and password but default Django user model need "username" and "password" arguments to create user. So here my testcase must raise "TypeError". And that what i tried to do here.

Answer (score -6):

Something like this should work:

```
thing = Thing.objects.create(name='1234')  
# not sure if you need here .get() or if. create() truncates the field on its own
self.assertEqual(thing.name, '123') # or: self.assertEqual(len(thing.name), 3)
```

-- but such test looks weird :-)

Also, note that MySQLdb backend will raise Warning exception to notify you of truncating the string, so you might want to check it with `assertRaises`.