# Python unit test how to assert message format

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

I have my Python unit test code that looks like the following

```
self.assertRaises(exc.UserError, module.function, args)
```

This basically asserts that a UserError was raised. I however cannot find how to check if the message in the exception matches my regular expression.

How can I do this? (I would prefer not to write any extra code and just leverage python unittest module features)

Comment: May this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215653/using-a-context-manager-with-python-assertraises    Should there be an assertRaisesRegex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python seems to have the same method in 2.7.3, the method is named "assertRaisesRegexp" so we do not (and should not) write our own wrappers :)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp

Answer (score 3):

```py
class ExtendedTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def assertRaisesWithMessage(self, msg, func, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.assertFail()
        except Exception as inst:
            self.assertEqual(inst.message, msg)
```

The standard unittest module provides no such method. If you use this more often you can use the code above and inherit from the ExtendedTestCase.

PS: Stolen from [How to show the error messages caught by assertRaises() in unittest in Python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672754/how-to-show-the-error-messages-caught-by-assertraises-in-unittest-in-python2-7) :)

Comment: "The standard unittest module provides no such method." False, see the answer of Calm Storm. However this solution works in python<2.7.